# How do I chain if statements in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I am using a logic operator in Jekyll but it's not working.

Page one, two and three all use the same layout (part of a multilingual solution, works good but requires logical loops for some layout control to keep things DRY.)

Here's the code:

```
{% if page.type == "post" %}
{% include post.html %}
{% elseif page.class == "contact" %}
{% include contact.html %}
{% else %}
{{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

If I break it down to just an `else` and an `if else` setup, with any two of the tree, everything works. But as soon as I use a third condition it breaks. Am I limited to two conditionals with Jekyll? I can potentially restructure to make a `case` operator applicable, but I'd prefer to understand the fundamental problem here. Thanks all.

Comment: Use `elsif` instead of `elseif`

Comment: See https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Designers

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In Jekyll/Liquid else-if is spelt `elsif`, i.e.:

```
{% if page.type == "post" %}
{% include post.html %}
{% elsif page.class == "contact" %}
{% include contact.html %}
{% else %}
{{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you continue to use {% else %} for even more statements?

Answer (score -2):

You can either use `else if` or `elsif`.
`elseif` is wrong and will throw an error.